# Vuforia and Unity : Unable to place mid-air objects or use ground plane

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm trying to place an object in mid-air and detect ground planes. When I follow the steps in the documentation, it doesn't work and I have the following error when debugging with adb:

PositionalDeviceTracker has not been Initialized correctly, unable to create anchors

I tried on an iPad running iOS 11.2, Pixel XL running Android 8.1.0 and a OnePlus 3T on Android 8.0.0 (which is not supporting ground planes but should work with mid-air anchors)
I tried each on Unity 2017.3.0p4, 2017.3.0f3, 2017.3.1f1 and even 2018.1.0b7

None of the above combination had any of these two features working.

I also use the image target feature and this one works perfectly.

I once managed to detect ground planes a month ago and I haven't changed my Unity version since then. However I updated both my Android and iOS devices at least once since then.

Please could you let me know if I'm doing anything wrong or if there's a known issue about that?

Thanks